# I get an "Unknown Source" exception uploading a Buffered Image

Tags: java, image-processing

To upload an Image I use this code

```
public static BufferedImage getSprite(String file,Object obj)
{
    BufferedImage sprite = null;
    try
    {
        sprite=ImageIO.read(obj.getClass().getResource(file));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
    }
    return sprite;
}
```

And then

```
public class Grass
```

{

```
BufferedImage grass=SpriteHandler.getSprite("/Resources/grass_tile.gif",this);



public void render(Graphics g)
{

    g.drawImage(grass, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

When I add this to the Main class with Grass grass=new Grass()
It catches`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Game.render(Game.java:99)
    at Game.run(Game.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

I tried everything, it works only if I put the "getSprite" method inside "render(Graphics g)", but in this way the program slows down

Comment: Upload or Load?

Comment: ImageIO.read(obj.getClass().getResource(file));
This should load an image inside the program
I think I wrote it incorrectly eheh

Comment: Could you post the main call?

Comment: Now it works
i put the main call in the public Main method

Comment: Now I put the call outside

Answer (score 0):

## Unkown Source

It happens because your jar, one of the JRE does not contain the source coude for the class. The JVM does not know the precise line that threw the exception. If the `.java` was in the jar, the stacktrace would contain the precise line. Change for a full JDK might solve this problem.

## NullPointerException

There's something wrong in your `render` method. Try to debug all the variables that are been using in the method to check if all are instantiated.

```
public void render(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(grass, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Checking the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) theres is not wrong with the parameters you are passing, `grass` could be `null`, the method would do nothing, and the fourth parameter is optional. So, I believe your `Graphics g` is null.